# Matching two string lists that partially match into another list

Tags: python, list, match

I am trying to match a List containing strings (50 strings) with a list containing strings that are part of some of the strings of the previous list (5 strings). I will post the complete code in order to give context below but I also want to give a short example:

```
List1 = ['abcd12', 'efgh34', 'ijkl56', 'mnop78']

List2 = ['abc', 'ijk']
```

I want to return a list of the strings from `List1` that have matches in `List2`. I have tried to do something with `set.intersection` but it seems you can't do partial matches with it (or at I can't with my limited abilities). I also tried `any()` but I had no success making it work with my lists. In my book it says I should use a nested loop but I don't know which function I should use and how regarding lists.

Here is the complete code as reference:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import random

def generateSequences (n):

    L = []
    dna = ["A","G","C","T"]
    for i in range(int(n)):

        random_sequence=''

        for i in range(50):
            random_sequence+=random.choice(dna)

        L.append(random_sequence)

    print(L)
    return L

def generatePrefixes (p, L):

    S = [x[:20] for x in L]
    D = []
    for i in range(p):
        randomPrefix = random.choice(S)
        D.append(randomPrefix)

    return S, D

if __name__ == "__main__":
    L = generateSequences(15)
    print (L)
    S, D = generatePrefixes(5, L)
    print (S)
    print (D)
```

edit: As this was flagged as a possible duplicate i want to edit this in order to say that in this post python is used and the other is for R. I don't know R and if there are any similarities but it doesn't look like that to me at first glance. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Do strings from `list1` require having every character from `list2` to be considered a match?

Comment: @StanleyR indeed, that is not a proper dupe target.

Comment: What do you mean by part of the string matches? What is your expected output for your example?

Comment: @rofls yes. `list2` contains strings that are the first 20 characters from randomly picked entries from `list1`. There is 15 entries in `list1` with 50 characters and i first take the first 20 characters from each entry then pick 5 of these at random and put them in `list2`. Now i want to make a list of 5 entries from `list1` that match `list2`. I am supposed to do that with a nested loop but I don't have a clue which method I should use.

Comment: A nested for loop is just two for loops (one _nested_ inside the other). Juanpam, EoinS and I all use them in our examples.

Comment: When searching list1 do you only want to check the first 20 chrs from each element as the prefix is only made  from this substr?

Comment: Thank you for the solutions. Much appreciated. I post here because i don't want to spam comments under every solution. All of them are working perfectly. I will pick rofls' solution because it is the closest to what I will use in my code but I will upvote every one of them since they are all correct and functional. @EoinS It doesn't really matter to me (for my purposes it can check all the characters) but out of curiosity: Would it speed up the program? Would it complicate it? Assuming I would ever use it for very large Lists.

Comment: Thanks @grindbert; the lists actually should have been outside of the function definition (see the edit), but if you got it working that's great :)

Comment: I used the lists that were made by the functions before that one (L and D) ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a nested for loop:

```
def intersect(List1, List2):
    # empty list for values that match
    ret = []
    for i in List2:
        for j in List1:
            if i in j:
                ret.append(j)
    return ret

List1 = ['abcd12', 'efgh34', 'ijkl56', 'mnop78']
List2 = ['abc', 'ijk']
print(intersect(List1, List2))
```

Answer (score 3):

This may not be the most efficient way, but it works

```
matches = []

for seq_1 in List1:
    for seq_2 in List2:
        if seq_1 in seq_2 or seq_2 in seq_1:
            matches.append(seq_1)
        continue
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
[l1 for l1 in List1 if any([l2 in l1 for l2 in List2])]
```

Comment: Sweet one liner, but it is actually slower than the nested for loop afaik. Also `any` would be much clearer instead of `sum`, from a reader's standpoint: `[l1 for l1 in List1 if any([l2 in l1 for l2 in List2])]`

Answer (score 1):

You can just compare strings, I remove any duplicates from a result list from list1 that contain list2 items.  This basically does it what you want:

```
f = []
for i in list1:
  for j in list2:
    if j in i:
      f.append(i)
result = list(set(f))
```