# Search in dictionary, merge key and value then put in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

in continuation of my last question ([Matching two string lists that partially match into another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37559280/matching-two-string-lists-that-partially-match-into-another-list)) I stumbled upon another problem. Perhaps i should first post the code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import random
import timeit

def generateSequences(n):

    RandomSequences = []
    dna = ["A","G","C","T"]
    for i in range(int(n)):

        randseq=''

        for i in range(50):
            randseq+=random.choice(dna)

        RandomSequences.append(randseq)

    return RandomSequences

def generatePrefixes(p, RandomSequences):

    First20Chars = [x[:20] for x in RandomSequences]
    RandomChoices = []
    for i in range(p):
        randomPrefix = random.choice(First20Chars)
        RandomChoices.append(randomPrefix)

    return First20Chars, RandomChoices

def searchReadsInList(RandomSequences, RandomChoices):

    start_time = timeit.default_timer()
    Matches_RS_RC = []
    for i in RandomChoices:
        for j in RandomSequences:
            if i in j:
                Matches_RS_RC.append(j)
    elapsed = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
    return Matches_RS_RC, elapsed

def makeSuffixDict(reads, extSize = 30, verbose = True):
    """
    Generates a dictionary with read-suffixes as values from a list of reads.

    Arguments:
    reads: list of str, reads for generating the dictionary
    extSize: int, length of suffixes stored as values in dict
    verbose: bool, whether to print feedback about results
    Returns:
    suffixDict: dict, dictionary with read-suffixes as values
    """
    dict = {}
    if not verbose:
        for i, read in enumerate(reads):
            prefix = read[0:-extSize]
            suffix = read[-extSize:]
            if prefix not in dict:
                dict[prefix] = [suffix]
            else:
                dict[prefix].append(suffix)
    else:
        unambiguous = set()
        ambiguous =  set()
        for i, read in enumerate(reads):
            prefix = read[0:-extSize]
            suffix = read[-extSize:]
            if prefix not in dict:
                dict[prefix] = [suffix]
                unambiguous.add(prefix)
            else:
                dict[prefix].append(suffix)
                if suffix in unambiguous:
                    unambiguous.remove(suffix)

                ambiguous.add(prefix)
        print("Reads:       ", len(reads), "\n",
              "Keys:        ", len(dict), "\n",
              "Unambiguous: ", len(unambiguous), "\n",
              "Ambiguous:   ", len(ambiguous), sep = "")
    return(dict)   


def searchReadsInDict(RandomSequences, RandomChoices):

    makeSuffixDict(RandomSequences)

    Matches_RC_Dict = []
    for i in RandomChoices:
        for j in dict:
            if i in j:
               Matches_RC_Dict.append(j)
    return Matches_RC_Dict


if __name__ == "__main__":
    RandomSequences = generateSequences(15)
    print ("genseq", RandomSequences)
    First20Chars, RandomChoices = generatePrefixes(5, RandomSequences)
    print ("genpre1", First20Chars)
    print ("genpre2", RandomChoices)
    Matches_RS_RC, elapsed = searchReadsInList(RandomSequences, RandomChoices)
    print ("searchList", Matches_RS_RC)
    print ("Time elapsed", elapsed)
    Matches_RC_Dict = searchReadsInDict (RandomSequences, RandomChoices)
    print ("SearchDict", Matches_RC_Dict)
```

What troubles me is `searchReadsInDict`. In `searchReadsInDict` I need to use the provided `makeSuffixDict` in order to create a dictionary. Then I need to match the strings randomly chosen by `generatePrefixes` with keys in the dictionary and combine the key and value into a string and put those into a list. For putting a key and value together into a string I found several methods, which worked by themselves but integrating them into the function always resulted in an error and I'm not sure where to put them in the function.
Another problem is that even running it as it is the output for `Matches_RC_Dict` is `[]`.
I hope anybody can help.

Comment: This would be clearer if you used better variable names than capital letters :)

Comment: I edited the Code. I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

With the permission  of 'cyphase' from the #python channel on freenode I'd like to post his great answer to prevent unnecessary work for others:

```
def searchReadsInDict(RandomSequences, RandomChoices):

    start_time = timeit.default_timer()
    mydict = makeSuffixDict(RandomSequences)

    Matches_RC_Dict = [rc+end for rc in RandomChoices for end in mydict[rc]]
    elapsed_sRD = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
    return Matches_RC_Dict, elapsed_sRD
```

Comment: I'd just like to say that this code was only provided as an immediate solution to the question posed in IRC. It's not how I would implement this ;).